# in GWT, change the background of Label when mouseover

Tags: gwt, user-interface, label, mouseover

I got this code:

```java
private class MyLabel extends Label implements MouseOverHandler, MouseOutHandler {
      public void onMouseOver(final MouseOverEvent moe) {
       this.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("E6D5D5");

      }



    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor("FFFFFF");
    }
}
MyLabel lb=new MyLabel();
lb.setText("ok");
```

But nothing happened, so what wrong in my code?

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register mouse handlers to Label.

```
lb.addMouseOverHandler(this);
lb.addMouseOutHandler(this);
```

Comment: actually it would be `lb.addMouse...(lb)` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

```
label.addStyleName("labelStyle");

.labelStyle : Hover {

 background : url("Mention your image");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep # infront of the color code